# Apple App Store - Pending Agreement status

Tags: ios, app-store

might be utterly stupid question, but I haven't been able to find simple and clear answer to this matter, what exactly means when my app is in pending agreement status? Is it because my account has been expired, and furthermore I am unable to delete my app from App Store until I renew my membership?

Comment: Have you accepted the updated agreement on the Apple developer site?

Comment: This is the message I get 

'Renew your membership to keep your access to program benefits and services. Once renewed, be sure to agree to your Paid Applications Agreement in the Agreements, Tax and Banking section of App Store Connect.'

I believe I can not do that until I don't renew my membership.
And another question, is there no other way to delete an app, just after I renew my membership?

Comment: If you don't renew your membership then your apps will be removed from the store anyway.  If you do renew your membership then you can delete your app through App Store Connect

Comment: Well my situation is tricky, I need to remove it to free up the name, so I was looking for some alternative solution, to avoid reneving membership just to delete an app, but it seems there is no other way. Is there a point to appeal to Apple support, and ask them to permanently remove application?

Comment: @БлагојеВуковитцх I'm facing same issue as you.
My Account is expired and I want to remove the app so the other account can use the name
Did you get solution for this?

Comment: I did apparently, my problem was I didn't own my account, I had limited roles as a developer to it, and I was't able to remove the app. And owner of my firm came in one day, logged in on his pc as a owner of that account, and managed to delete it, regardless the account has expired a while ago
Well at least he presented me that was the situation, I am not 100% sure he didn't renew old account just in order to delete old app. Hope this helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply Renew your Developer account/membership . costs $99

https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership

Answer (score 9):

My case was publishing paid apps & not about membership,

So I visited Agreements Section & filled necessary forms

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/

Comment: This link is helpful because it clearly states on this page that my apps are unavailable due to my subscription expiring. Thank you!

Comment: What Enes mentioned is correct. There is still some steps to be completed for any app that is not free.